# How to force redrection when url contain question mark in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL :

```
www.domain.com/PageName:ArgumentValue1,ArgumentValue2
```

I would like to make a redirection to

```
www.domain.com/apex/f?p=alias:PageName:ArgumentValue1,ArgumentValue2
```

I have done so far :

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./apex/f?p=alias:$1 [L]
```

The redirection works properly except when an Argumentvalue has a question mark.

Is there any way to force such a redirection even if there is a question mark in an argument ?

PageName, ArgumentValue1 and ArgumentValue2 are all dynamic variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give example of a non-working URL? Also what error do you get? May be add `QSA` flag in rule.

Comment: A question mark in such URL would mean that you did not correctly encode the arguments. That is nothing you can fix afterwards. You need to cure the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: @anubhava the error I have is that if I have a question mark in the argument let's say 'AA?BB', it's cut and I get only 'AA'

Comment: @arkascha : I didn't code any argument. I'm connected to a payment server, that after each payment transaction, it should redirect to a URL I provide and adds the transaction identifier at the end of my URL. And their transaction Id they have question marks. So whenever the payment is done I got a URL with a question mark on it

Comment: That means that payment server is broken. You should ask them to fix it.

Comment: OK, all fine, thanks and sorry for trying to help. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use your rules as this:

```
# no query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ apex/f?p=alias:$1 [L]

# with query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ apex/f?p=alias:$1\?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

However do note that if you want to capture `?` as pert of REQUEST_URI then it should be encoded as `%3f`. So e.g. `AA?BB` would be used as `AA%3FBB`